# tf-agent, QNetwork => DqnAgent w/ tfa.optimizers.CyclicalLearningRate

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-agents

Is there an easy native way to implement [tfa.optimizers.CyclicalLearningRate](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/CyclicalLearningRate) w/ [QNetwork on DqnAgent](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial)?

Trying to avoid writing my own DqnAgent.

I guess the better question might be, what is a proper way to implement callbacks on DqnAgent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tutorial you linked, the part where they set the optimizer is

```
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)

agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent(
    train_env.time_step_spec(),
    train_env.action_spec(),
    q_network=q_net,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter)

agent.initialize()
```

So you can replace optimizer with whatever optimizer you would rather use. Based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam) something like

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=tfa.optimizers.CyclicalLearningRate)
```

should work, barring any potential compatibility issues coming from that they are using the tf 1.0 adam in the tutorial.